# How to flatten a column of arrays in DataFrame, apply a function, and restore the structure?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks as follows. There are two columns, the second of which contains numpy arrays that differ in shape (here: `(2, 1)`, `(2, 2)`, `(2, 3)`). Example:

```
   class                         data
0      0                  [[3], [17]]
1      1            [[9, 5], [8, 19]]
2      1  [[8, 16, 13], [17, 19, 10]]
```

I would now like to flatten the `data` column to get a 1D array `[3, 17, 9, 5, 8, 19, 8, 16, 13, 17, 19, 10]`, apply a function to this vector, and restore the original shape of the DataFrame. For example, if I want to subtract the mean of the vector from all elements, the desired output is this:

```
   class                      data
0      0               [[-9], [5]]
1      1       [[-3, -7], [-4, 7]]
2      1  [[-4, 4, 1], [5, 7, -2]]
```

How can I best achieve this transformation?

Edit for @mozway:

I generated the DataFrame like this:

```
data = []

np.random.seed(8)

for i in range(1, 4):
    data.append(np.random.randint(0, 20, (2, i)))

category = {"class": [0, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(category)
df["data"] = data
```

A function to transform the 1D array mentioned before would be `arr -= np.mean(arr)`.

Comment: 1- can you provide a reproducible constructor to set up the input (it's annoying to copy/paste), 2- can you provide a meaningful example of the function you would use?

Comment: @mozway I added more information to the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `flat` is an array as below:

```
[-9.  5. -3. -7. -4.  7. -4.  4.  1.  5.  7. -2.]
```

One approach could be the following:

```
def nested_unflatten(da, placeholder):
    res = []
    for e in placeholder:
        if isinstance(e, Iterable):
            res.append(nested_unflatten(da, e))
        else:
            res.append(next(da))
    return res


flat = np.array([-9.,  5., -3., -7., -4.,  7., -4.,  4.,  1.,  5.,  7., -2.])
un_flat = nested_unflatten(iter(flat), df["data"])
print(un_flat)
```

**Output**

```
[[[-9.0], [5.0]], [[-3.0, -7.0], [-4.0, 7.0]], [[-4.0, 4.0, 1.0], [5.0, 7.0, -2.0]]]
```

If you are also interested in a `flatten` function:

```
def flatten(da):
    res = []
    for e in da:
        if isinstance(e, Iterable):
            res.extend(flatten(e))
        else:
            res.append(e)
    return res
```

It can be used to obtain `flat` from the example, like:

```
 flat = np.array(flatten(df["data"]), dtype=np.float64)
 flat -= np.mean(flat)
```

Comment: I had the same approach in mind ;)

Comment: It works perfectly and looks very elegant. Thanks a lot for the solution!